# Unclear on how to derive the coefficients (in functions or constant numbers) of the matrix coefficients of a 2D rotation (by 90 degree)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, boolean-algebra

The matrix computed to the lower left is what I came up with to determine if I understand how coefficients are computed, but I can not seem to reason mathematically to compute the matrix both as a fixed function format for a 2d rotation operation clock wise across a reference origin with a unit circle  and four quadrants.   How can I use the unit circle sign properties and trigonometric functions, namely sin, and cos to find the corresponding coefficients both in the case where the transformation matrix rotates a point  90 degrees clock wise, an operation I am not sure is called possibly a fixed transformation, vs a matrix transformation that transformation that rotates a point using an arbitrary angle on the unit circle.  Please clarify.   I have not yet grasped this key concept in spite learning how to perform matrix computations in school.

[image]

Comment: Note: sgn, is a piecewise linear function with jump discontinuity at y = -1 for x < 0, and y = +1 for x > 0, where x = 0 corresponds to a single point on (0,0)  x = 0, y = 0

Comment: Is the 2x2 rotation matrix coefficients for 90 degree counter counter clockwise rotations, simply determined by the difference of the signs of the axes of concern (x,y) in the respective 4 quadrants, using a boolean difference operation (xor, xnor)?